# Date value different in CP and database

Tags: database, datetime

Have a site registering users.
The user record in the CP says they registered at 11:39 June 12.

The database 'dateCreated' says 10:39.

The site settings timezone are UTC+1 BST.

PHP config date.timezone is Europe/London (actual location)
and Default timezone is UTC.

If I turn off UTC +1 in Craft timezone settings to UTC then front end user record matches database.

What I can't figure out for sure is what time did they really register? :)

Comment: I just learned to kinda live with it. Here in the Netherlands, 1 hour ahead of London time I have the same issue but then 2 hours ahead. Tagging along here for when there is an explanation / solution. What I'm thinking is that the amount of + hours of UTC just gets added aswell to the time it should be.

Comment: It looks like the server/db time is the 'real' local time and the interface just makes a change in date when setting timezone is changed. Which is a bit weird for time sensitive content.......or embargoed press releases...

Answer (score 4):

Craft stores all dates in UTC to the database, no matter what timezone you configure in settings.

When (user) models are populated, e.g. for use in the CP, `DateTime` objects are created from these values and the objects’ timezones are set to the one you configured.

If you want to output a user’s `dateCreated` attribute in a date format that includes the timezone you can easily do that in a template using the `date` Twig filter. This will return the date in ISO 8601 format using your configured default timezone.

```
{{ user.dateCreated|date('c') }}
```

You can also output the date formatted for a diffenent timezone.

```
{{ user.dateCreated|date('c', 'Europe/Paris') }}
```